# Keras trained model exported with older version of Keras ( < 2.2.0 )

Tags: keras, version-control

Is it possible to update a trained model saved in a file without retraining it ?

I found the model on the web and I would like to use it but it uses `Merge` layers which are not supported by newer version of Keras, making it impossible to load with new versions.

Comment: Which version of Keras are you using to load the model? And please add the full error trace.

Comment: Use joblib as well! But never faced any error with saving and loading models in keras